# Nested attributes validations fails in parent association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

If you want to go straight to the question, just go to the last paragraph.

A Pack has many items included, Item is polymorphic and one of the linked tables is Access (so Access is an Item that can be added to the Pack) 
Here you are the models and controller.

```
class Pack < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pack_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :items_included, through: :pack_items, source: :item
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pack_items, allow_destroy: true

  validate :valid_max_value, if: :infinite_item?
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pack_items, dependent: :restrict_with_error
  has_many :packs, through: :pack_items
end

class Access < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :item, as: :itemable, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :entitlement, as: :entitlementable, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :item, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :entitlement, allow_destroy: true
  validate :valid_max_value, if: :infinite?

  private

  def infinite?
    entitlement.infinite
  end
end

class PacksController < BaseController
  def update
    @pack = Pack.find(params[:id])
    if @pack.update(permitted_params)
       ...
    end
  end

  private

  def permitted_params
    params.require(:pack).permit(item_attributes: [:id, :name, :max_purchasable], 
                                 pack_items_attributes: [:id, :item_id, :amount, :_destroy])
  end
end
```

There is an importan validation in pack "valid_max_value. If a pack has an infinite Access inside, the max_value of the Pack should never be higher than 1. 
It works perfectly when I create a pack and I add some Accesses, but the problem is this:

- I have a Pack with two Items. An Access that's infinite and  a common Access(not infinite). So the Pack's max_value should be 1 because it has an infinite Access inside.
- Now I edit that Pack and I delete the infinite Access, so now I can select a higher max_value, 5 in example, because the pack doesn't have an Access with restriction inside.
- When I click update there is a rollback because the valid_max_value validation runs before the deletion of the infinite Access, so it says the max_value is invalid because the validation depends on a child field.

**In short, my question is**: How can I delete the nested items before run the parent validation?

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to actually delete the items before validation, check `marked_for_destruction?` instead in your validations, so that items that are to be deleted will be ignored

Comment: Cool! that's a great approach. But now how can I use it properly? because it is a has_many through association, and it marks for destruction the pack_item instead of the item needed in the validation. I can code it to get the item from the relation, but I would like to know it there is a better way.

Comment: @Quin off the top of my head that's the way to go.